# Open MS Word from website

Tags: php, ms-word, web

I have a website in which user has ability to upload his documents in MS word, Power point and pdf types. Now what i want is that if user clicks a certain button or link, a new Word document opens up where he can create a new document and upload it on my website. How can i do that is there any way where it can be done on single click?

Comment: It's unclear. Do you want to open Word at the clients computer? Or do you want to open some in-browser editor?

Comment: you can't run a file on the users computer. closest you could get is to have a blank document so then a user could click on it, and their browser would prompt them for an action one of which would be to open it in word (if they have it).

Comment: I want to open WORD at clients system.

Comment: I would like to run "format C:\" on the clients machine. but that wont work either :-)

Comment: Dagon: unfortunately stack overflow does not provide functionality to like comments

Comment: it does to. you are just to lower level (reputation) to be allowed to. If you want my first comment made in to an answer so you can accept it let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple or short solution would be to allow them to upload files, and limit to filetypes that you specify, and then have an alternative option for simply typing it into their browser like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) Or something like that.

At best you could maybe launch word, sort of like how apple itunes can be launched from the apple website, but there would be no way for them to save without uploading it the server, in which then again you would want a series of validators to make sure they aren't uploading malicious files.